# Unable to add/remove items in Global and current navigation in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, navigation, global-navigation, current-navigation

I am trying to add items in Global Navigation in a SharePoint online site.

When I goto site settings and Navigation under look and feel (/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationsettings.aspx), I see empty Global Navigation and Current Navigation.

When I add something (Link & Headings) under it and click ok, it is not getting saved. Even when I click on edit links on left navigation and add a link and save it, it is not getting saved.

Not sure what the issue is, any guidance is appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Is this site associated with a hub site? Clear browser caches to see if it proceeds. Also, there seems to be a time-delay(one or two days) to reflect on the navigation as per my experience.

Comment: Yes it is associated to Hub site and the hug navigation is appearing in modern pages. There are quite a few classic pages and I am trying to configure the Global navigation for them, but when I add links and click ok, they are not getting saved